# Checkbox boolean always shows false?

Tags: c#, umbraco

I currently have this code to check if my checkbox is checked or not, and return "hide" if true and "none" if false. However I can not get it to work. It only prints out "none" even if the checkbox is true. What am I doing wrong?

```
var hideOnMobile = Model.Banner.GetPropertyValue<bool>("hide_mobileres") ? "hide" : "none";

<div class="banner banner-small @bgClass @textColorClass @fontSizeClass @hasBgClass @hideOnMobile">
```

UPDATE:

Attempted this:

```
var hideOnMobile = (Model.Banner.AncestorOrSelf().Children.Any(x => x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("hide_mobileres"))) ? "hide" : "none";
```

Same issue, only getting none printed out.¨

Fixed it...

Had the wrong property in umbraco. had to choose true/false..

Comment: Try this `(Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf().Children.Any(x => x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("hide_mobileres")))`

Comment: var hideOnMobile = (Model.Banner.AncestorOrSelf().Children.Any(x => x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("hide_mobileres"))) ? "hide" : "none"; still prints out none :( @MohitShrivastava